# Coded Systems and dense subsets

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, reference-request

A shift space $(X, \sigma)$ is a *coded system* if there exist a countable collection of finite words $(\omega^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, called generators, such that $X$ is the closure of the set of sequences obtained by freely concatenating the generators.

In Lind and Marcus book *An introduction to symbolic dynamics and coding,* page 451 there is stated a nice topological equivalence: $(X,\sigma)$ is a coded system if and only if $X$ contain an increasing sequence of transitive subshifts of finite type whose union is dense in $X$.

It is mentioned that this equivalence is due to Krieger and it is cited on Blanchard and Hansel paper *Sofic constant-to-one extensions of subshifts of finite type*, Proc. Amer.Math. Soc. **112** (1991), 259-265. The given reference is a personal communication between W. Krieger and the authors.

I would like to know if there exist a reference where I can find the proof of this statement.

Comment: I think you could find a proof in the book by Blanchard and Maass, "Topics in Symbolic Dynamics and Applications, but I don't have the book handy so can't check for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to the library right know. I'll let you know if the proof is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the book referred to in Doug Lind's comment didn't have what you're looking for, a proof of this statement can be found in Section 2 of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1869067):

Doris Fiebig and Ulf-Rainer Fiebig, [Invariants for subshifts via nested sequences of shifts of finite type](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=90747), *Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems* **21** (2001), pp 1731-1758.

There are also some other references there, including an article by Krieger with the proof, and another paper by Fiebig and Fiebig with lots more information on coded systems.

Comment: Thanks Vaughn, a direct explicit reference is exactly what we needed here! -Doug